# pandas DataFrame resolve internal references to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
a = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'q': [], 'obj': 901},
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'q': [(3, 3)], 'obj': 907},
    {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'q': [], 'obj': 884},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'q': [(2, 2), (3, 3)], 'obj': 485},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'q': [], 'obj': 814},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'q': [], 'obj': 491},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 1, 'q': [], 'obj': 822},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 2, 'q': [], 'obj': 752},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 3, 'q': [(1, 3), (2, 1)], 'obj': 739}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I want to add a new column, `ref` which is a list of `obj` for every `(x, y)` reference in `q`. I know that I can iterate through `q` for each row but that's slow and silly.

The result should look like

```
   obj                 q         ref  x  y
0  901                []         NaN  1  1
1  907          [(3, 3)]       [907]  1  2
2  884                []         NaN  1  3
3  485  [(2, 2), (3, 3)]  [814, 739]  2  1
4  814                []         NaN  2  2
5  491                []         NaN  2  3
6  822                []         NaN  3  1
7  752                []         NaN  3  2
8  739  [(1, 3), (2, 1)]  [884, 485]  3  3
```

What is the pandas way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the logic that `ref` column calculated?

Comment: can you explain how ref is calculated. It's not clear.

Comment: `ref` is a lookup of the obj value of the the `x, y` coordinates defined in `q`. So `[(2, 2)]` has one item and has the value of obj for the row where `x=2` and `y=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup in `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['x','y'])
df['ref'] = [[df1.at[y, 'obj'] for y in x] if x else np.nan for x in df1['q']]
print (df)
   obj                 q  x  y         ref
0  901                []  1  1         NaN
1  907          [(3, 3)]  1  2       [739]
2  884                []  1  3         NaN
3  485  [(2, 2), (3, 3)]  2  1  [814, 739]
4  814                []  2  2         NaN
5  491                []  2  3         NaN
6  822                []  3  1         NaN
7  752                []  3  2         NaN
8  739  [(1, 3), (2, 1)]  3  3  [884, 485]
```

Comment: Great. Trying it now. I presume I can extend this similarly where I have more than two columns (x, y) and something like (x, y, z) too.

Comment: @Vishal - Ya, then need change only `df1 = df.set_index(['x','y'])` to `df1 = df.set_index(['x','y', 'z'])`

Comment: Is it possible to refactor `df['ref'] = ...` for more readability without compromising on speed?

Comment: @Vishal - What do you think refactor? Speed here is a bit problematic, because pandas cannot working vectorized with nested tuples.

Comment: Will this throw errors if invalid index values are presented to df.at?

Comment: @coldspeed - What is reason your question?

Comment: Just curious... If this is a case OP might have, your code could throw errors.

Comment: @coldspeed - So you know answer, sure it return errors if not matched.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of a pandaic way to do this, but iteration will help.

```
mapping = {(x, y) : z for x, y, z in df[['x', 'y', 'obj']].values.tolist()}
df['refs'] = [
    [mapping.get(idx) for idx in idxs] if idxs else np.nan for idxs in df['q']]

   obj                 q  x  y        refs
0  901                []  1  1         NaN
1  907          [(3, 3)]  1  2       [739]
2  884                []  1  3         NaN
3  485  [(2, 2), (3, 3)]  2  1  [814, 739]
4  814                []  2  2         NaN
5  491                []  2  3         NaN
6  822                []  3  1         NaN
7  752                []  3  2         NaN
8  739  [(1, 3), (2, 1)]  3  3  [884, 485]
```

Comment: Trying it now. And the solution makes sense. Do you know which of the two solutions offered so far will be faster of the two and scale better as `len(df)` gets to be 1e5, 1e6 and 1e7?

Comment: @Vishal difficult to say. Both look like viable solutions in my eyes. I use a dictionary to do the mappings, he utilizes the dataframe index as a mapper. Valid approaches, both.

Comment: @Vishal Have you figured out what solution to use? You can upvote all answers you found helpful, and accept the one you ended up using.